# SQL: Getting multiple line entries (from same table) in one line?

Tags: sql, sybase

I already looked the questions that may have my answer, but none really has so:

I have a table like this:

```
id | timestamp | date       | identifier | personnel_number
00 | 00000     | 2000-01-01 | A          | 01
01 | 28800     | 2000-01-01 | B          | 01
02 | 29000     | 2000-01-01 | A          | 01
03 | 45000     | 2000-01-01 | B          | 01
.
.
.
```

I need the results (in this case all four of the filled lines) in half the amount of lines (alternating between identifiers A and B). I already tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     a.timestamp,
     b.timestamp
FROM table AS a
LEFT JOIN table AS b
     ON a.personnel_number = b.personnel_number
     AND a.date = b.date
     AND a.identifier != b.identifier
WHERE a.personnel_number = [SOMEVALUE]
     AND a.date = [SOMEDATE]
     AND a.identifier = "A"
     AND a.id > b.id
     AND a.timestamp < b.timestamp
GROUP BY a.timestamp, b.timestamp
ORDER BY a.timestamp ASC
```

But that does not give me the required two lines with

```
a.timestamp#1, b.timestamp#1
a.timestamp#2, b.timestamp#2
```

but gives me

```
a.timestamp#1, b.timestamp#1
a.timestamp#1, b.timestamp#2
a.timestamp#2, b.timestamp#2
```

I also got it wrong another way by using MIN (false way obviously). Thought it was right because there only were two results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     a.timestamp,
     MIN(b.timestamp)
FROM table AS a,
     table AS b
WHERE a.personnel_number=[SOMEVALUE]
     AND b.personnel_number=[SOMEVALUE]
     AND a.date=[SOMEDATE]
     AND b.date=[SOMEDATE]
     AND a.identifier = "A"
     AND b.identifier = "B"
     AND b.id > a.id
GROUP BY a.timestamp
ORDER BY a.timestamp ASC
```

My results were like this then, so obviously not correct either^^°

```
a.timestamp#1, b.timestamp#1
a.timestamp#2, b.timestamp#1
```

Any idea at all how to get my needed result and of course results like it with more table entries?

Edit: As to answer the question, I use Sybase.

Comment: Edited the answer in the above post too but maybe you see my answer faster this way: I'm using Sybase.

Comment: Move the b conditions from WHERE to ON to get true left join behavior! (As it is now you get inner join result.)

Comment: No need for SELECT DISTINCT when you've got that ORDER BY.

Comment: NEVER use `select distinct` and `group by` in a single select (because `select distinct` is utterly redundant in such a query so it is just wasteful)

Answer (score 0):

Could do with a bigger test data set but this should point you in the right direction:

***EDIT*** - Completely revised approach using the LAG function

**Test Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE times
    ([id] int, [timestamp] int, [date] datetime, [identifier] varchar(1), [personnel_number] int)
;

INSERT INTO times
    (id, [timestamp], [date], identifier, personnel_number)
VALUES
    (00, 00000, '2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'A', 01),
    (01, 28800, '2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'B', 01),
    (02, 29000, '2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'A', 01),
    (03, 45000, '2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'B', 01),
    (04, 36000, '2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'A', 02),
    (05, 55000, '2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'B', 02);
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT a.personnel_number, a.timestamp AS timestampa, b.timestamp AS timestampb
  FROM(SELECT id
            , [timestamp]
            , [date]
            , identifier
            , personnel_number
         FROM times) AS a
  JOIN(SELECT id
            , [timestamp]
            , LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY personnel_number, [date], [timestamp]) AS previd
            , LAG([timestamp]) OVER (ORDER BY personnel_number, [date], [timestamp]) AS prevtimestamp
            , [date]
            , identifier
            , personnel_number
         FROM times) AS b
    ON b.prevtimestamp = a.timestamp  
   AND b.personnel_number = a.personnel_number 
   AND b.date = a.date
```

**Results:**

```
personnel_number    timestampa  timestampb
1                   0           28800
1                   28800       29000
1                   29000       45000
2                   36000       55000
```

Comment: Okay ... in your SQL Fiddle it works just great, just tried it out. But in the Interactive SQL Sheet of Sybase it doesn't. Like I said, need to but "b.timestamp" behind "ORDER BY a.timestamp" as well and get the wrong results (same wrong results as in my first mentioned try above) whereas in the Fiddle I don't.

Comment: Ok ... found out it's because of that SQL-Anywhere error 149, but I can't do it as in the Fiddle now o.O